# Firemonkey Gradient Colors on Android

Tags: delphi, firemonkey-fm3, delphi-xe8

I have come across a rather funny issue. I have a form with its `Fill` set to `Gradient`.

On Windows, IOS and OSX, the gradient is drawn as it should be. But on Android, the colors are wrong. Any ideas?

```
object Form1: TForm1
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Form1'
  ClientHeight = 480
  ClientWidth = 640
  Fill.Kind = Gradient
  Fill.Gradient.Points = <
    item
      Color = xFFFFC600
      Offset = 0.000000000000000000
    end
    item
      Color = xFFFFF100
      Offset = 1.000000000000000000
    end>
  Fill.Gradient.StartPosition.Y = 0.500000000000000000
  Fill.Gradient.StopPosition.X = 1.000000000000000000
  Fill.Gradient.StopPosition.Y = 0.500000000000000000
  FormFactor.Width = 320
  FormFactor.Height = 480
  FormFactor.Devices = [Desktop]
  DesignerMasterStyle = 0
  object Button1: TButton
    Position.X = 8.000000000000000000
    Position.Y = 8.000000000000000000
    TabOrder = 0
    Text = 'Button1'
  end
end
```

Windows:
[image: Windows Screenshot]

OSX:
[image: OSX Screenshot]

IOS:
[image: IOS Screenshot]

Android:
[image: Android Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

You are using Delphi, right? Because, I have never seen that syntax used in a Pascal based language, nor was I able to get your code running under Delphi 10 Seattle. Was it created by a code-generator?

I have, however, written up the gradient you were trying to get using Delphi 10 Seattle and Firemonkey.
It works and looks the same on every device, even on Android:

```
procedure TForm1.FormPaint(Sender: TObject; Canvas: TCanvas;
  const ARect: TRectF);
var
  locGradient: TGradient;

begin
  with Canvas do begin
    BeginScene;

    // Create and initialize the gradient object
    locGradient := TGradient.Create;
    with locGradient do begin
      Color   := $FFFFC600;
      Color1  := $FFFFF100;

      StartPosition .Y  := 0.5;

      StopPosition  .X  := 1;
      StopPosition  .Y  := 0.5;
    end;

    // Assign the created gradient object to the fill property of the canvas
    with Fill do begin
      Kind      := TBrushKind.Gradient;
      Gradient  := locGradient;
    end;

    // Create a rectangle which represents the gradient
    FillRect( ARect,  0, 0, AllCorners, 1.0 );

    EndScene;
  end;

  FreeAndNIL( locGradient );
end;
```

This doesn't necessarily answer your question as to **why** your colour values are messed up on Android only using your code, but then again, your code doesn't seem to follow the *common* Delphi syntax convention.

Comment: That's the source code of my form. You shouldn't have to write one line of code... Just open your form file and replace it with what I have provided

Comment: Ah, I see. That's very enlightening!

I've got your code running the way you explained, under Delphi 10 Seattle and Delphi XE8. It works just fine on my end - the colours are displayed correctly on my Android device.

I am using a **Motorola G 2nd Generation** running **Android 5.0.2**. My Delphi XE 8 Android SDK is configured to use the **Android SDK 24.0.2 32 bit**.

What Android and Android SDK version are you using?

Comment: @Renpai. You seriously have never looked at .dfm code before!? How long have you been programming in Delphi?